# How many commentaries are there on the Purva Mimamsa Sutras?

Tags: translation-request, purva-mimamsa, resource, jaimini

The [Purva Mimamsa Sutras](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purva_Mimamsa_Sutras) written by [Jaimini](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaimini) is one of the most important Indian philosophical texts and forms the basis of [Mimamsa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimansa) school of thought.

Now, how many commentaries are there of these Sutras? I'm only aware of the [Sabara Bhashya](https://archive.org/details/Shabara.Bhasya.tr.by.Ganganath.Jha). Are any of these commentaries translated in English and  available free online?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Shabara, Prabhakara and Kumarila wrote commentaries on Purva-Mimamsa sutras.

1. Prabhakara school of Purva-Mimamsa translated by Ganganatha Jha.
2. Purva-Mimamsa in its sources by Gangantha Jha. It presented 3 commentaries side by side.
3. A HINDU CRITIQUE OF BUDDHIST EPISTEMOLOGY Kumarila on perception
   The “Determination of Perception” chapter of
   Kumarila Bhatta’s Slokavarttika Translation and commentary John Taber. I don't know much about this book. It might be useful, I am not sure.

Comment: Those (1-3) are books about the Purva Mimamsa school.  They are not actual commentaries on the Purva Mimamsa Sutras, though they contain some quotes from commentaries.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are topic-based discussions, like - the idea of the soul according to Prabhakara, Shabara and Kumarila.